# Why won't Rails' with_locale method allow additional URL parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, actionmailer, rails-i18n

I've got this `Mailer` in my Rails 7 project:

```
# app/mailers/quote_mailer.rb

class QuoteMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def quote_mail(quote)
    @quote = quote
    @user = quote.user
    @client = quote.client
    @account = quote.account
    I18n.with_locale(@quote.locale) do
      mail(
        :from     => @user.email,
        :to       => @client.email,
        :subject  => "New Quote"
      )
    end
  end

end
```

---

```
# app/views/mailer/quote_mail.text.erb

Dear <= @client.name %>

Please click here to download your Quote:

<%= quote_download_url(@quote.token, :namespace => @account.namespace) %>

Best regards

<%= @user.name %>
```

---

```
# config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope ':locale', :locale => /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do

    scope ':namespace' do

      resources :quote_downloads, :only => [:show]

    end

  end

end
```

Unfortunately, the link in the email can't be built and throws an error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show",
> :controller=>"quote_downloads",
> :locale=>"VmKHoRSx79AEatcoHtPz8uun", :namespace=>"volkswagen"}, missing
> required keys: [:id], possible unmatched constraints: [:locale]

It seems that my `namespace` parameter confuses Rails.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Add the relevant routes from `rails routes` to your question.

Comment: @smathy: I just added my `routes.rb` above.

Comment: Running `rails routes -c quote_downloads` returns this: `quote_download GET  /:locale/:namespace/quote_downloads/:id(.:format)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not expect `I18n.with_locale` to set `locale` in URLs unless [`locale` is configured as default URL option](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-url-params). I would only expect it to change the locale of the rendered email.

But you can just pass it manually in your mailer like this:

## app/views/mailer/quote_mail.text.erb

```
Dear <= @client.name %>

Please click here to download your Quote:

<%= quote_download_url(@quote.token, namespace: @account.namespace, locale: @quote.locale) %>

Best regards

<%= @user.name %>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks!